# Finding a text from a string using regex in Hadoop

Tags: sql, regex, hadoop

I have following string :

```
BCRIS-QUEBEC.C67950210QC.5147650116.O5000977510.RD02.0026.00001.DistributionPair.O
```

In Hadoop I am trying to pull RD02 and put it under Dist_Cu_Cable column.

This string is just an example and RD02 could be any text. I am using following code but not getting desired result. ¬

```
MAX(
CASE 
    WHEN lower(associatedwoi_id) LIKE '%distributionpair%' 
    THEN 
        CASE
            WHEN associatedwoi_id REGEXP '(?i)([^.]+)\.[^.]+\.[^.]+\.DistributionPair\.' 
            THEN REGEXP_REPLACE(associatedwoi_id, '.*(?i)([^.]+)\.[^.]+\.[^.]+\.DistributionPair\..*', '\\1')
        END
END
) AS Dist_Cu_Cable,
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Have you tried just testing the regex on https://regexr.com/?

Comment: My goal is to parse out text which is between 3rd and 4th dot before DistributionPair (or between 4th and 5th dot from beginning of the string) from associatedwoi_id column and assign it to Dist_Cu_Cable column. However when I run this in Hadoop it retruns me a single digit instead of RD02 in this case

Answer (score -2):

It sounds like this is like a PowerShell replace, whereby anything that is matched will be replaced, even if you have it in a non capturing group. So you need to ensure the regex, only matches this specific bit of text, by using look forwards or backwards by tweaking your Regex like this:

```
(?i)([^.]+)(?=\.[^.]+\.[^.]+\.DistributionPair\.)
```

Comment: I tried this in python and works very well. But in hadoop when I run following code it gives me an error saying invalid regex expression. Maybe Hadoop does not accept look ahead or behind expression. Is there another way to do it?
 `WHEN associatedwoi_id REGEXP '(?i)([^.]+)(?=\.[^.]+\.[^.]+\.DistributionPair\.)'             
  THEN REGEXP_REPLACE(associatedwoi_id, '(?i)([^.]+)(?=\.[^.]+\. 
   [^.]+\.DistributionPair\.).*', '\\1')`

Comment: ah looks like hadoop requires a double backslash to escape characters, can you try: `(?i)([^.]+)(?=\\.[^.]+\\.[^.]+\\.DistributionPair\\.)` instead